# Difference between square brackets and curly brackets in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

A bit of a newbie question: whats the difference between square brackets `[]` and curly brackets `{}` in Matlab? When is it appropriate to use either?

Update: its actually in the Matlab docs under "Special Characters".

Comment: As noted, your answer is probably in the documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/specialcharacters.html). However, it's unclear what you mean by "angle" brackets, which typically refer to `<>`, but these symbols are not use to "bracket" anything in MATLAB as far as I know.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A square bracket creates a vector or matrix, whereas curly brackets creates a cell array.

When working with numbers, I'd say that 99% of the time, you will use square brackets. Cell arrays allow you to store different types of data at each location, e.g. a 10x5 matrix at (1,1), a string array at (1,2), ...

```
x = [1 2 3]; #% matrix with values 1, 2, 3
y = {1, 'a', x}; #% cell array storing a number, a character, and 1x3 matrix
```

Here is the MATLAB documentation on cell arrays: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html

Comment: I think OP is wrong in his terminology. Angle brackets refer to `<>`, which are used as relational operators. `[]` are simply called brackets or square brackets.

Comment: I see, yes, my answer is about `[]` vs `{}`.

Comment: @yoda - you're absolutely correct. I've updated my question from "angel brackets" to "square brackets".

Answer (score 2):

This paper answered my question above in a very elegant manner. The paper explains Matlab arrays to someone who is more familiar with non-array based languages such as C++, C#, Java, and Python:

[MATLAB array manipulation tips and tricks - Peter J. Acklam](https://web.archive.org/web/20151004200803/https://thalesians.com/archive/public/academic/computing/papers/Acklam_2003.pdf)